# Show: $f=x^p - \alpha$ irreducible and inseparable in field $F(\alpha)$, where $charF=p>0$ and $\alpha$ transcendental over F

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

To show it is irreducible I just show that $\sqrt[p]\alpha \notin F$, since it is a zero of the polynomial in question and, if it is not, then it cannot be reducible. (Correct me, if I am wrong here. I am not entirely sure if that's true.) $\sqrt[p]\alpha \notin F$ obviously holds, because otherwise $\alpha \in F$ and a minimal polynomial $x-\alpha$ is enough to show that $\alpha$ isn't transcendental. Which is a contradiction and therefore $f$ is irreducible.

To show that is inseparable we look at $f' = (x^p)' - (\alpha)' = px^{p-1}-0 = px^{p-1}$

Now since $char(F)=p$ it holds that $py=0, \forall y \in F$ (This is the second part I am not sure about). And so $f' = 0$, which proves by definition that it is inseparable.

Could you please tell me if this is a viable solution and if not then I could use hint.

Comment: For your first "not entirely sure" see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370500/if-xp-a-has-no-zeros-in-a-field-f-of-characteristic-p-where-a-in-f-is).

Comment: @DietrichBurde They talk about no zeroes in $F$. Does it also hold for when just one zero is not in $F$?

Comment: For $g(x) \in K[x]$, if $\deg g = 2$ or $3$ then the lack of a root of $g(x)$ in $K$ implies it is irreducible, but that is generally not true when $\deg g \geq 4$. Consider $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ in $\mathbf Q[x]$: it has no rational root but is reducible! So the fact that for $x^p - a$ in characteristic $p$, a lack of roots implies irreducibility is an *unusual* example because ordinarily the lack of roots above degree $3$ doesn't imply irreducibility.  So proving that requires a careful argument.

Comment: @KCd Ok, I am getting very confused now. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370500/if-xp-a-has-no-zeros-in-a-field-f-of-characteristic-p-where-a-in-f-is) it says that it is irreducible if no zeros are in the field. Isn't it irreducible if it doesnt have linear factors?

Comment: For the *specific* case of $x^p-a$  in characteristic $p$, a lack of roots implies irreducibility. But that is *not* because there is general result in math that a polynomial having no roots is irreducible!!  In degree 2 or 3 over all fields, it is  true that a lack of roots implies irreducibility, but for degree $4$ and higher it is *typically false* that a lack of roots implies irreducibility. So the fact that for $x^p-a$ in characteristic $p$ a lack of roots implies irreducibility is *quite unusual* and needs a careful argument. I feel like I am repeating what I already wrote before.